# Revival badge when another answer scored first

Tags: support, badges, revival-badge

I got the revival badge for [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35084/4794) answer for being the first answer, more than 30 days after the question was asked, to get an answer score of two.  While it's true that I was the first to answer after 30 days of inactivity, and that answer did get a score of two, someone else answered shortly after me and scored more than 2 before I got a score of two.  However, when I eventually got my second vote, I got the badge.

Is that by design?  Should I have "dibs" on the revival badge even if I did not get the first answer that earned a score of 2?

I tagged as discussion because I don't see this as a mistake, just clarifying if this was intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design; the moment your answer reached a score of two *and* it was posted at least 30 days after the question was asked *and* no **earlier** answer has a score of 2 or up your answer qualified for the badge.

In other words, it doesn't matter if any answers that were *posted* later got to a score of 2 first, all that matters is that no earlier answers did.

For that matter, [the other answer qualified too](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/revival?userid=440); it too got to a score of 2 before any earlier answers did.

Answer (score 2):

Both conditions have to be met (time of posting *and* score), so any answer *after* yours would not qualify for this badge.

As reference for a more detailed discussion on badge requirements, see the FAQ [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244), specifically [Answer badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/168244).